# Docker image error: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: image, docker

I created a docker image using a script. The docker image got created successfully but when I am trying to run on the browser, I get the following message

[image]

I tried to resolve the error using webapps but it is popping up the same message.

Comment: That's not a docker error message. Please include a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

It is happening probably because the directory `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps` is empty. as you can see in the description in the [Docker Hub official image](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/):

> You can then go to http://localhost:8888 or http://host-ip:8888 in a browser (noting that it will return a 404 since there are no webapps loaded by default).

To solve that, you can just create a new image and copy and paste what you want inside of the folder `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps`.

For example, you can find inside of the folder `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps.dist` files of the tomcat webapp manager. If you try to see what is that you can run:

```bash
$ docker run -it tomcat:10 ls /usr/local/tomcat/webapps.dist
ROOT  docs  examples  host-manager  manager
```

Now that you know what is inside of the folder `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps.dist`, create your own Dockerfile and copy and paste this folder to `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps`:

```
FROM tomcat

RUN cp -R /usr/local/tomcat/webapps.dist/* /usr/local/tomcat/webapps

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Build the image:

```bash
$ docker build . -t custom-tomcat
```

Execute the image:

```bash
$ docker run -d -P custom-tomcat
```

Check the port opened:

```bash
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE           COMMAND             CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                         NAMES
58390eab3fec   custom-tomcat   "catalina.sh run"   9 minutes ago    Up 9 minutes    0.0.0.0:49163->8080/tcp, :::49163->8080/tcp   lucid_joliot
```

Open your browser and check if it works:
[image: Tomcat Manager Webapp]